# How to not run cron script twice on the same MongoDB document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cron

I need to run cron script (written in nodejs) every 5 min against MongoDB documents to male some stuff work (optimize their structure for example). My cron scripts described in crontab like following:

```
# min hour mday month wday command
*/5  *    *    *     *    /usr/local/bin/node /var/www/run/script.js
```

The main problem is that my-script during handling MongoDB should prevent handling the same document at the same time twice.

How could I guarantee that crown will not handle MongoDB at the same time twice?

Comment: I don't understand why 1. this would ever happen and 2. why it would be a problem. Could you elaborate on *why* you are doing this? Then we can maybe gain a better understanding of what you need.

Comment: As Philipp mentioned more information will be more than welcome. With the level of information you have submitted here a possible idea: have you tried to set a flag into the document during the execution of the script (if compatible to your use case), that you check in your code (if or filter).L ike that you know if the script has  already been executed on this doc.

Comment: @Philipp I can't provide a full information about my purpose because it's long history but main purpose that I need is fetch MongoDB document and make some stuff on it and save it back to database. At now I set 10 min but later I'll set 30 sec and in this case I can get collisions.

Comment: @Tug Grall what if cron script fails and my document will be zombie? How could I remove flag in this this case?

Comment: Honestly without more information it is quite hard to help. Keep in mind that each "update/insert" is atomic so you should be able to find a way to "flag" the documents that has been created/updated by a specific process and, cleanup if need (if needed! this is where it is hard to help without any business context)